# Does Facebook's Graph API offer Alerting for new API Versions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to know if Facebook's Graph API offers a method for alerting me if a new version of the API is available? Or if there is some sort of email I can subscribe to that will alert me?

This way I can get as soon as possible notifications of API versioning updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not such a thing yet. In my experience I check the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/) once a week in order to stay update with any change.

Moreover, althought Facebook is releasing versions more often, they usually set a long range deadline.